# Issue: Sans Digital 8-BayTower Storage Enclosure causing PC to restarts

Tags: windows

I am using Sans Digital 8-Bay eSATA RAID 0/1/10/5/JBOD Tower Storage Enclosure w/ 6G PCIe Card TR8M+B (Black) with Rocket Raid RR642L Card

[http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16816111168&nm_mc=EMC-IGNEFL101013&cm_mmc=EMC-IGNEFL101013-*-EMC-101013-Index-*-ServerRAIDSystems-_-16111168-LM2A](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16816111168&nm_mc=EMC-IGNEFL101013&cm_mmc=EMC-IGNEFL101013-_-EMC-101013-Index-_-ServerRAIDSystems-_-16111168-LM2A)

Detail of main original issue:
http://www.avsforum.com/t/1498850/file-tranfer-speed-issue-with-storage-enclosure-system-tr8m-b

So the new issue is i got Rocket Raid RR642L card and speed issue has gone but now i am seeing unstable system , i dont trust it as it is very not stable

where my pc auto restarts and it make me think if it is not the card as i replaced it 3 times it could be the unit

I am trying to setup FlexRaid " Raid over file system " with this unit and my pc and it is not happing and i am not sure if i return this unit back or if i need to troubleshoot it longer

It bought this unit in October and now it is December and no luck with it so far , just issues after issues

The windows logs can be found here:
http://paste2.org/pZpfXKeh

I see This error:

```
The device, \Device\Scsi\rr640l1, did not respond within the timeout period.
```

and i see this error:

```
The device, \Device\Harddisk0\DR0, is not ready for access yet.

The device, \Device\Harddisk3\DR3, is not ready for access yet.

The device, \Device\Harddisk4\DR4, is not ready for access yet.

The device, \Device\Harddisk4\DR6, is not ready for access yet.

The device, \Device\Harddisk5\DR5, is not ready for access yet.

The device, \Device\Harddisk9\DR28, is not ready for access yet.

The device, \Device\Harddisk5\DR25, is not ready for access yet.

The device, \Device\Harddisk10\DR27, is not ready for access yet.

The device, \Device\Harddisk10\DR24, is not ready for access yet.

The device, \Device\Harddisk4\DR6, is not ready for access yet.
```

also see this

```
Faulting application name: ASPFSVS64.exe, version: 2.0.0.2, time stamp: 0x4cf70fca
Faulting module name: ASPFSVS64.exe, version: 2.0.0.2, time stamp: 0x4cf70fca
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000000000000a356
Faulting process id: 0x70c
Faulting application start time: 0x01ceec0d6fe5fd7d
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\Disk Unlocker\ASPFSVS64.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\Disk Unlocker\ASPFSVS64.exe
Report Id: b01d3ab8-5800-11e3-9858-c8600022b15f
```

also see this from AMD Raid

```
Task 20 timeout on port 1 target 1 at LBA 0x00 (Length 0x1)
```

my system is running on 2 SSD on Hardware Raid 1 with windows 7 x64bit

also see this

```
The driver detected a controller error on \Device\Ide\IdePort1.
```

Not sure why bitlock on windows 7 is active but i never set it up

also see this

```
Encrypted volume check: Volume information on cannot be read.
```

and see NTFS error on drive G

```
The default transaction resource manager on volume G: encountered a non-retryable error and could not start. The data contains the error code.
```

and see this

```
The device, \Device\CdRom0, has a bad block.
```

Can someone advise as i have no idea what the logs mean

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar stability problems with a Sans Digital TowerRAID TR8M-BP and a Highpoint RocketRAID 622.  After a few days of testing I found the problem to be the RocketRAID drivers, specifically the x64 drivers.  On all x86 systems (even the same hardware), the systems were stable, but under a 64 bit system the TowerRAID was useless.  If you have an extra HD and a couple hours to spare, try unplugging the x64 OS drive and install an x86 OS + x86 drivers.